# How to use small caps for all biblatex (style=alpha) references with capital letters?

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to use small caps for all biblatex (style=alpha) references that consist out of capital letters?

The following MWE should demonstrate the goal:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hammond,
    author       = {Hammond, Christopher},
    title        = {The basics of crystallography and diffraction},
    date         = 1997,
    publisher    = {International Union of Crystallography and Oxford 
                    University Press},
    location     = {Oxford},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=british},
    sorttitle    = {Basics of crystallography and diffraction},
    indextitle   = {Basics of crystallography and diffraction, The},
    shorttitle   = {Crystallography and diffraction},
    annotation   = {A \texttt{book} entry. Note the \texttt{sorttitle} and
                    \texttt{indextitle} fields as well as the format of the
                    \texttt{publisher} field},
}

@article{sarfraz,
    author       = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
    title        = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic 
                    capturing of the font outlines},
    year         = 2002,
    volume       = 26,
    number       = 5,
    pages        = {795-804},
    issn         = {0097-8493},
    journal      = {Computers and Graphics},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with an \texttt{issn} field},
}

@book{companion,
    author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
    title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
    date         = 1994,
    edition      = 1,
    publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
    location     = {Reading, Mass.},
    pagetotal    = 528,
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    sorttitle    = {LaTeX Companion},
    indextitle   = {LaTeX Companion, The},
    shorttitle   = {LaTeX Companion},
    annotation   = {A book with three authors. Note the formatting of the 
        author list. By default, only the first name is reversed in the
        bibliography},
}

@article{murray,
    author       = {Hostetler, Michael J. and Wingate, Julia E. and Zhong,
    Chuan-Jian and Harris, Jay E. and Vachet, Richard W. and
    Clark, Michael R.  and Londono, J. David and Green, Stephen
    J. and Stokes, Jennifer J.  and Wignall, George D. and Glish,
    Gary L. and Porter, Marc D.  and Evans, Neal D. and Murray,
    Royce W.},
    title        = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules with core
                    diameters from 1.5 to 5.2~{nm}},
    journaltitle = {Langmuir},
    date         = 1998,
    subtitle     = {Core and monolayer properties as a function of core 
                    size},
    volume       = 14,
    number       = 1,
    pages        = {17-30},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    indextitle   = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules},
    shorttitle   = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with \arabic{author} authors. 
                    By default, long author and editor lists are 
                    automatically truncated. This is configurable},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Single Author \cite{hammond} ($\leftarrow$ leave untouched)

Two Authors \cite{sarfraz} ($\leftarrow$ use small caps)

Three Authors \cite{companion} ($\leftarrow$ use small caps)

Many Authors \cite{murray} ($\leftarrow$ leave untouched)

\bigskip

Preferred output (at least within the text and optionally also within the bibliography list):
[Ham97], \textsc{[Sr02], [Gms94]}, [Hos+98]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want `\textsc{Sr}` or do you want `\textsc{sr}`? (I'd find the former a bit confusing as it somehow puts more emphasis on the first name ...)

Comment: @moewe I had exactly the same concerns. But the former is prefered.

Comment: @moewe I thought about it again and replaced the word ideally in the MWE with "optionally". The idea behind this update: Typographically optimized output in the text - no differentiation (typographically induced ranking) in the bibliography list. The option is for those who think that the ref-labels [Xxx] should be identical between text and list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well testing for capital letters is not so easy, but *if* as your example implies you want the change for two and three authors you could try to do it like this.

I didn't test what happens if there are Umlauts etc and if `\MakeSentenceCase` can handle them. Also I don't think that this a good style, I find it confusing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hammond,
    author       = {Hammond, Christopher},
    title        = {The basics of crystallography and diffraction},
    date         = 1997,
    publisher    = {International Union of Crystallography and Oxford
                    University Press},
    location     = {Oxford},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=british},
    sorttitle    = {Basics of crystallography and diffraction},
    indextitle   = {Basics of crystallography and diffraction, The},
    shorttitle   = {Crystallography and diffraction},
    annotation   = {A \texttt{book} entry. Note the \texttt{sorttitle} and
                    \texttt{indextitle} fields as well as the format of the
                    \texttt{publisher} field},
}

@article{sarfraz,
    author       = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
    title        = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic
                    capturing of the font outlines},
    year         = 2002,
    volume       = 26,
    number       = 5,
    pages        = {795-804},
    issn         = {0097-8493},
    journal      = {Computers and Graphics},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with an \texttt{issn} field},
}

@book{companion,
    author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
    title        = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
    date         = 1994,
    edition      = 1,
    publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
    location     = {Reading, Mass.},
    pagetotal    = 528,
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    sorttitle    = {LaTeX Companion},
    indextitle   = {LaTeX Companion, The},
    shorttitle   = {LaTeX Companion},
    annotation   = {A book with three authors. Note the formatting of the
        author list. By default, only the first name is reversed in the
        bibliography},
}

@article{murray,
    author       = {Hostetler, Michael J. and Wingate, Julia E. and Zhong,
    Chuan-Jian and Harris, Jay E. and Vachet, Richard W. and
    Clark, Michael R.  and Londono, J. David and Green, Stephen
    J. and Stokes, Jennifer J.  and Wignall, George D. and Glish,
    Gary L. and Porter, Marc D.  and Evans, Neal D. and Murray,
    Royce W.},
    title        = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules with core
                    diameters from 1.5 to 5.2~{nm}},
    journaltitle = {Langmuir},
    date         = 1998,
    subtitle     = {Core and monolayer properties as a function of core
                    size},
    volume       = 14,
    number       = 1,
    pages        = {17-30},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    indextitle   = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules},
    shorttitle   = {Alkanethiolate gold cluster molecules},
    annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with \arabic{author} authors.
                    By default, long author and editor lists are
                    automatically truncated. This is configurable},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumcomp{\value{\thefield{labelnamesource}}}{=}{2}}
    or
    test {\ifnumcomp{\value{\thefield{labelnamesource}}}{=}{3}}
  }
    {\textsc{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}}
    {#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Single Author \cite{hammond} ($\leftarrow$ leave untouched)

Two Authors \cite{sarfraz} ($\leftarrow$ use small caps)

Three Authors \cite{companion} ($\leftarrow$ use small caps)

Many Authors \cite{murray} ($\leftarrow$ leave untouched)

\bigskip

Preferred output (at least within the text and optionally also within the bibliography list):
[Ham97], \textsc{[Sr02], [Gms94]}, [Hos+98]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since we explicitly ask for `author` here, this does not scale to well for entries where the label is taken from `editor`. Do you think it would be possible to check for the "`labelalphaname`" number instead?

Comment: @moewe: I don't think that biber stores this number, but there is the field `labelnamesource` . I changed `\value{author}` to `\value{\thefield{labelnamesource}}`. Seems to work fine ...

Comment: Brilliant. I'm thinking if one could avoid mentioning the 2 and 3 explicitly by testing against `maxalphanames`

Comment: Thank you very much, moeve for the bounty and UlrikeFischer for the (very) acceptable answer - which seems to be at least a good starting point for further testing and investigation!